# PHP date function not appearing

Tags: php, date

I'm confused as to why my date function does not appear in this code when i open it in chrome. The file is save as a .php file.  I'm brand new to PHP just started yesterday and wanted to try adding some code into my HTML code i have at the moment any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>David Iacovino</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="62,54,100">
<center>
<h1>Page</h1>
<br></br>
<font size="4", color = "gray", face = "times new roman">Monday Evenings 6:30-9:15</font>
<img src="http://cdn.bleacherreport.net/images_root/slides/photos/000/268/563/cesar_logo1_display_image.jpg?1277255126" height= 100 width= 100>
<br></br>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/"</a>Facebook</a>
<br></br>
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    echo date("l");
?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you testing this on a server with PHP enabled?

Comment: try echo date('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create .php file and not .html file to run php code. And also need php server to run php code. You might need apache like server. Try to download xampp and then try

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
date_deafault_timezone_set('UTC');  // deafault
```

to

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // misspelled default

echo date("l");
```